# SDL on OSX with fullscreen - CMD-TAB not working

Tags: macos, sdl

I'm using SDL on OSX, putting the display into fullscreen by using SDL_SetWindowFullScreen(SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN). What I find is that when doing this, the CMD-TAB hotkey does not work. This is quite different behaviour as to bringing up a normal window and manually expanding it to fullscreen - the latter works fine.

Has anybody else experienced this? I'm using a slightly (locally) modified version of 2.0.4. Also I've tried the latest (as of yesterday) version from Mercurial. Does not seem to make much difference. Testing on El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by [this forum discussion](http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=9968&sid=a76395496ab77aa7a02003c4dc3953d6), instead of `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN` you could use `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP` to solve that issue.

Comment: Well that sorted out the CMD-TAB, but I now note that CMD-H (hide) no longer works!

Comment: I wonder if hiding full screen "windows" is actually supposed to work (for instance, I can't hide a full screen video player using Cmd-H).

Comment: Eventually came to the same conclusion - true for Finder too.